# CakePHP - working on xampp, not working on wamp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have an app which works on XAMPP (login) (windows) and when I deploy it on server or on other local machine with WAMPP, it won't log in. Database is the same and configuration is same.

Is there any difference between XAMPP and WAMPP (both mod_rewrite are working)?

Thank you.

Comment: no, there isnt (if you are using the same PHP version etc). there must be some other issue involved.

Comment: `it won't log in` it not help much to solve your problem. Turn on debug mode, and check out for logs.

Comment: list phpinfo for both,see difference,see other configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTF - 8 withoud BOM in Notepad++ wasn't specified so that was the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `httpd.conf` file to:

```
load mod_rewrite
```

... and I did restart Apache services after doing that.